# Jquery, CSS DIV's, Switch Statements

Tags: jquery, css, switch-statement, html

Using jQuery -

I have

I have 4 div's -  div1, div2, div3 & div4
 - that when rolled-over unique text and images are displayed into a separate div called div5, content will depend on what div you have rolled-over...

I was thinking of using a switch statement, but am not sure how to pass the divs through the switch cases...??

- I would also like the animations to .stop(). animating the current animation and begin the new one when any of the four divs are rolled over.. ??
- I would also like to have a click function on the four divs that turns off the mouseout rollOver effect and will only change when one of the other four divs is rolled-over or clicked...??

here is what I have come up with so far.. basically individual animation effects, having a bit of trouble tying them all in together...??

```
// HTML ----

<div id="maincolumn">   
<div id="js_bg">
    <div class="rollOversHolder">
        <div class="triggerFirstJsSpacer"></div>
        <div class="mainManaged"></div>
        <div class="triggerJsSpacer"></div>
        <div class="mainSolutions"></div>
        <div class="triggerJsSpacer"></div>
        <div class="mainCloud"></div>
        <div class="triggerJsSpacer"></div>
        <div class="mainLicense"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="jsCopysHolder">
        <div class="copy1Holder">
            <div class="leftCopy1">
                Test text _01
            </div>
            <div class="leftCopy2">
                Test text _02
            </div>
            <div class="leftCopy3">
                Test text _03
            </div>
            <div class="leftCopy4">
                Test text _04
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="copy2Holder">
            <div class="copy1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
/*CSS ----*/

.main1{
background:url(../images/it_sol_norm.png);
width:103px;
height:133px;
float:left;

.main2 {
background:url(../images/it_sol_norm.png);
width:103px;
height:133px;
float:left;

.main3 {
background:url(../images/it_sol_norm.png);
width:103px;
height:133px;
float:left;

.main4 {
background:url(../images/it_sol_norm.png);
width:103px;
height:133px;
float:left;

.triggerFirstJsSpacer {
width:45px;
height:133px;
float:left;

.triggerJsSpacer  {
width:70px;
height:133px;
float:left;

jsCopysHolder {
width:682px;
height:230px;
border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
float:left;
font-size:.9em;
color::#5A5A5A;
margin-top:37px;
margin-left:15px;

copy1Holder {
width:330px;
height:150px;
float:left;

.copy2Holder {
width:330px;
height:150px;
float:left;

.leftCopy1 {
width:230px;
height:auto;
display:none;
position:relative;
color:#4d4d4d;

.leftCopy2 {
width:230px;
height:auto;
display:none;
position:relative;
color:#00FF00;

.leftCopy3 {
width:230px;
height:auto;
display:none;
position:relative;
color:#0099FF;

.leftCopy4 {
width:230px;
height:auto;
display:none;
position:relative;
color:#FF0000;




    //jQuery ----

jQuery(".main1").mouseover(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy1").is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy1").slideDown("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".main1").mouseout(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy1").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy1").slideUp("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".main2").mouseover(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy2").is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy2").slideDown("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".main2").mouseout(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy2").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy2").slideUp("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".main3").mouseover(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy3").is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy3").slideDown("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".main3").mouseout(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy3").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy3").slideUp("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".mainLicense").stop().mouseover(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy4").is(":hidden")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy4").slideDown("medium");
    }
});

jQuery(".mainLicense").stop().mouseout(function() {
    if (jQuery(".leftCopy4").is(":visible")) {
        jQuery(".leftCopy4").slideUp("medium");
    }
});
```

Comment: A list of technologies is _not_ an appropriate question title.

Answer (score 0):

You would just have to create handlers for the divs through a class:

```
$('.div_class').hover(function(){
    //stop all animation
    $('.div_class').stop();

    //animate the current one
    $(this).animate(options);
}).click(function(){
    //not sure what you want on click....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lastDiv;
$("#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4").hover(function(){
  lastDiv = $(this);

 $(this).animate({});//Pass the animation properties

 $("#div5").html("Set the required text");
  //You can access the rolled over div using $(this)

}, function(){
  $(this).stop();
}).click(function(){
  if(lastDiv)
    lastDiv.stop();

});
```

Comment: Thank-you for your post, great use of this and varaibles, i understand a little more from reading over your reply.

Although I am not sure that method will work with mine.. I am using css to display and hide my divs, my text is sitting on the index page, though it starts off with a css - display:none; and then jquery changes the css values... Any ideas, when working with this method..??